# Вопрос по json и htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, javascript, json

Суть проблемы, из js поступает json строка "poll":{"create":true,"question":"test1","options":["test2","test3"]}

В php получается такая строка - $options = urldecode(json_encode($project['poll']['options']));

Вроде получается всё гуд, но мне нужно избавиться от всех html тегов в options, я делаю htmlspecialchars($options)

Оборачиваю htmlspecialchars полученную строку options

В конечном результате - когда строка заноситься в БД, она получается такого типа `[&quot;test2&quot;,&quot;test2&quot;]`

Как мне правильно оборачивать входные данные ['poll']['option']

Чтобы я смог добавить строку в базу, не `[&quot;test2&quot;,&quot;test2&quot;]`, а `["test2","test2"]`

Comment: Так делайте `strip_tags` а не `htmlspecialchars` перед сохранением в БД. `htmlspecialchars` обычно при выводе используют

Comment: @jekaby Спасибо чувак